# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'colspan' of undefined

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-server-2012-r2, odoo-12, fleet

Hi i'm Using Odoo12 in windows server 2012 r2 with pycharm 2019 
 i install the module fleet and i apply some modification everything was workinng fine , once i want to create a fuel vehicle log i get this message error appear but all other thing work creation of vehicle .... except this 
Here is The Error Mesaage that i got :

```
Erreur:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'colspan' of undefined

http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/466-dc380e9/web.assets_backend.js:1635
Retraçage :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'colspan' of undefined
    at http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/466-dc380e9/web.assets_backend.js:1635:34
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/465-25ab684/web.assets_common.js:12:558)
    at Class._renderInnerGroup (http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/466-dc380e9/web.assets_backend.js:1634:63)
    at Class._renderTagGroup (http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/466-dc380e9/web.assets_backend.js:1648:228)
    at Class._renderNode [as _super] (http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/466-dc380e9/web.assets_backend.js:1640:246)
    at Class._renderNode (http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/466-dc380e9/web.assets_backend.js:2840:50)
    at Class._renderNode (http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/465-25ab684/web.assets_common.js:3541:371)
    at http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/466-dc380e9/web.assets_backend.js:1645:17
    at Function._.map._.collect (http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/465-25ab684/web.assets_common.js:13:270)
    at Class._renderOuterGroup (http://10.0.1.178:8069/web/content/466-dc380e9/web.assets_backend.js:1644:18)
```

Need your help , Please is Emeregency 
Thank you

Best regards
eyounes

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same problem when trying to access the sequence form view. The problem was the translation of the view, the "span colspan = '2'" tag was removed in the translation

Image with the problem:

[image]

Try changing the language in your user preferences. If there is no error, it is a translation problem.